# Are there any known languages in the intersection of NP and co-NP but not in P?

Tags: complexity-classes, np

We currently don't know the relationship between NP and co-NP, but would it be possible to show whether the intersection is equal to P? I can't think of any languages in both NP and co-NP, but not in P.

Comment: Note that you can't prove that any NP problem is outside of P as that would imply that P != NP

Answer (score 3):

Proving that $P= NP \cap$ co-$NP$ is an open problem and believed to be unlikely since Integer factoring decision problem is in both $NP$ and co-$NP$ but conjectured to be outside $P$.